# How to make view stick to the right of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Is there a way make view stick like here?

little text:

[image]

a lot of text:

[image]

Comment: Yes, with a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but you may be talking about a TextView having the attribute `android:ellipsize="end"`